# Get the value of a text field

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a view with the Select view statement and I was wondering how do I get the value of a text field so that the view only shows the documents of that text field?

Answer (score 1):

If the database is full text indexed, then you can use the `[fieldname]="<value>"` syntax to do a one time search for specific content.

Source: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/full-text-syntax

If you want to change the view to only show documents that has a specific value in a field, then you need to edit the view using Domino Designer. Here you need to change the select to something like this:

```
SELECT Form="yourform" & Yourfieldname = "<value>"
```

Comment: He asks for SELECT... your Syntax is for Fulltext search...

Comment: @TorstenLink I read it as a search in an existing view. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer! However, what if I want to do a select statement based on the name itself? For example, Yourfieldname = Yourfieldname? I have other conditions in the select statement as well but I want to show the documents in the view by that field name in which the user has entered. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use `Yourfieldname!=“”` to search for documents with content in the field